# Можно ли у файлов откатить время (временную метку создания) назад?

Tags: время, лицензирование

Есть файлы на ПК: звуковые (mp3, wav, oggg и т.д.), картинки, видео и т.д.

Возможно ли в современном мире изменить их временные метки, чтобы показывало, что файл создан не 1 марта 2021, а 1 марта 2000? Есть ли такие программы?

Сам я не ищу. Меня интересует сам такой вопрос и возможность. Например, если есть свой музыкальный продукт, например песня и для защиты авторских прав **один из пунктов** будет сохранение мелодии на разные носители с датой изготовления. И если кто-то спёр её, то показать: "нет дядя, вот исходник и вот дата, я - автор".

Comment: [SetFileTime](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfiletime)

Comment: @AntonShchyrov да, плохо, что можно всё поменять. . Печаль)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно. Во-первых, нет особых проблем изменить системное время перед созданием файла. Кроме того, для разных ОС и ФС существуют системно зависимые способы манипуляции всеми временами файлов (создания, модификации, доступа и т.п.).

Для фиксации авторского права можно использовать метки времени, криптографические или какие другие, которые можно получить у независимых удостоверяющих центров.

Comment: да, плохо, что можно всё поменять. Проверил - действительно можно сохранить задним числом. Печаль. Спасибо за ответ